# Export all columns of the attribute table from a shapefile as a txt. file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, export

I would like to export the attribute table of a shapefile.

I used a cylindric equal area projection and then manually added a column in which I calculated the geometry (area in m2). I like to export the whole attribute table (including the newly added column regarding the area) as a txt. file.

[image]

When i do the export of the attribute table (via export data), all columns get exported except the last one with the area.

[image]

I took into account that perhaps the name of the column could be too long and tried to change it (at least the alias).

[image]

But this had no effect and the column with the calculated area was still not included within the exported file.

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Try the table to table tool to export to CSV?

Comment: As a workaround you could use the table buttons select all and copy selected records to clipboard, and paste that into a text file.  You might also export to a csv file.  To avoid exporting the geometry in Settings - Data Sources - Feature Attributes and Tables you can select Copy Features as plain text no Geometry.  As for your dropped field,  I remember having last fields dropped exporting tables in ArcMap to dbf if there were nulls in the last field first record or second to the last field last record.

Comment: I tried both options but they did not work. Also the table to table tool skips this one relevant column. And I could not use the copy to clipboard function after selecting all records. However, I found by accident a way (not sure how) of creating a txt file of the attribute table twice in an incomplete way. Even though both tables were as such incomplete they covered together all the information. I proceeded then with the merging of the relevant information outside of ArcMap and the problem is solved.